Virtual Environment Active in VS Code After Removing Virtual Environment Folder
I had a directory like this:
-rootname
|
--project
  |
  --.venv
  -- [etc.]

I was working in VS Code with wsl2-Ubuntu within the virtual environment in ".venv". When I was done, I deactivated the environment with deactivate. Then, I clicked on the ".venv" folder and deleted it.
The next day, I opened VS Code and saw this: (.venv) myhostname:rootname$. This has happened many times before, and I was able to enter deactivate before reinstalling a new virtual environment and reactivating. Today, I am not able to deactivate. Instead, I get the error: deactivate: command not found.
What is going on here?
After reinstalling .venv and activating the new environment, I see the following: (.venv) (.venv) myhostname:rootname$. I can easily deactivate one .venv, but I get the same command not found error when attempting to deactivate the second environment.

This morning, after opening VS Code, the issue persists. Then, after closing out VS Code, and after some time re-opening VS Code, the .venv prefix finally disappeared. That is weird. I changed nothing. The problem resolved itself after a day and closing and reopening VS Code a few times.
